# Architectural Advice: How to listen to Database change in realtime?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

I am trying to develop a system where some predictive/estimated results are stored when a new entry arrives in centralised database(MySQL). I have multiple micro-services writing into that database, where I have patched my code which pushes the record into the Kafka, and consumer of kafka is estimating and pushing result back to DB.

My problems are:

1. Multiple micro-services are written in either Node or Python, so i need to write logic in both.
2. With code injection in multiple place, maintenance is turning out to be an issue.

**Potential solution**
1. Create another microservice, which becomes producer for the Kafka.

Can we have even more well managed system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check about `Change Data Management`. You can use `Debezium` utility which listens to the event happening on your database and pushes them over to your Kafka topic.

Workflow can be summarized as:

1. The Record arrives at DB.
2. Transaction logs are written by DB.
3. Debezium connector tracks the logs, and pushes the changes to Kafka via Kafka connect.
4. You can now subscribe to Kafka topic and estimate on the record.

Gains:

1. Even if your Debezium will be down, when it comes up it will give all changes happened during the downtime. It will be fault-tolerant in that sense.
2. You will be listening to centralize database instead of pushing from multiple services. This enables a single source of truth principle.